# Is it possible to navigate navhost frgamment from other fragment at main activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, navigation, navigation-drawer

Here i am using left navigation drawer and i did this with nav graph and nav controller and nav drawer menu xml. But now i need to reload nav host fragment when i click from left navigation drawer first  item nav_home but i cant. but it is possible for other menu item click to go other fragment but i face problem when i am navigatting to nav host fragment. Is it Possible ?????? Or I need to change the whole process ?????

Here is my main activity Code where i am navigate

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

```
   if (item.itemId == R.id.nav_logout){
       val intent = Intent(this, SignInActivity::class.java)
       intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
       val troyeeAppSession = TroyeeAppSession(this)
       // start the new activity
       startActivity(intent)
       troyeeAppSession.setStatus(false)
       Log.d("ClickTest","LogoutClick")
   } else if (item.itemId == R.id.nav_order_list){

       Log.d("ClickTest","Order List Click")
       val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this!!,R.id.nav_host_fragment)
       navController.navigate(R.id.nav_order_list)
       drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START,true)
   } else if (item.itemId == R.id.nav_collection_list){

       Log.d("ClickTest","Collection List Click")
       val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this!!,R.id.nav_host_fragment)
       navController.navigate(R.id.nav_collection_list)
       drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START,true)


   } else if (item.itemId == R.id.nav_home){

       Log.d("ClickTest","Home Button Click")
      /* val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this!!,R.id.nav_host_fragment)
       navController.navigate(R.id.nav_collection_list)*/

       val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController.navigate(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
       
       drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START,true)




   }


    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm following the logic and problem here, but I would create `BaseActivity`

```
abstract class BaseActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
    abstract val navController: NavController
}
```

Then I would extend your Activity with it and do something like this:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override val navController: NavController get() = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)//You main nav controller
}
```

This way you will be able to use your `navController` in any Fragment by using
`(requireActivity() as? BaseActivity)?.navController`

tip: create BaseFragment or extension function to reuse the code eg for Fragment.

```
fun Fragment.navigate(@IdRes id: Int) {
    (requireActivity() as? BaseActivity)?.navController?.navigate(id)
}
```

Or from any other place that you can get your Activity.
And then your if statement can become `when`

```
when(item.itemId){
    R.id.nav_logout -> {
    //your code
    }
    R.id.nav_order_list -> {
       this.navigate(R.id.nav_order_list)
       drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START,true)    
    }
}
```

Also remember that navigation will fail with an exception if direction is unknown, so it's good practise to wrap it with try{} and handle the error.

Hopefully this will help, if not please try describing at which point the app is failing.